# referring to a class from another file with the scope operator (::)

Tags: c++, scope

I have a `main.cpp` file, with `#include "engine.h"` in the beginning.

Inside `engine.h` there's

```
#include "myObject.h"

namespace nmspc{
   MyObject obj1;

   //some code here
}
```

and `myObject.h` has:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyObject{
public:

   void helloWorld(){
      std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
   }

}
```

Why can't I refer have in my `main.cpp` something like this?:

```
int main{

   nmspc::obj1::helloWorld();

   return 0;
}
```

instead I have to type either `nmspc::obj1.helloWorld()`, or `MyObject::helloWorld()`. But I'd like to use the one above.

Comment: `MyObject::helloWorld()` - that can't work. You can't call a member function without an object. What object should be used to call `helloWorld` function with `nmspc::obj1.helloWorld()`?

Comment: You should not define objects in header files.

Comment: Give a look to static methods, maybe it's what you're looking for

Comment: The reference would look like `nmspc::obj1.helloWorld();`, but there are other things wrong, too.

Comment: You say *But I'd like to use the one above.* - but that is invalid c++ syntax, so **why** would you want to use it?

Comment: Good point Adrian. Instead of `cout << "hello";` I want to use `put the word hello on the screen please;`. How can I do this in C++?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using [static member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static), by adding the keyword `static` before the method declaration. if you do this, the function will not be associated with an actual instantiation of the class, so cannot access any member variables or non-static member functions.

In general, you wouldn't access static member functions through the created object, but through the class name (although it is possible to call it through an instance).

```
class MyObject{
public:

   static void helloWorld() {
      std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
   }

}

int main{

   MyObject::helloWorld();

   return 0;
}
```

Whether or not you *should* do this is dependant on the context. Your program is simple enough that's its not immediately clear why you would make it a static member function, rather than a free function, but I'm not sure I have enough context to give advice.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all
incorrect header content

```
#include "myObject.h"

namespace nmspc{

   MyObject obj1;

   //some code here
}
```

this should be in a cpp module i.e: a translation unit
as it is an instantiation i.e. a `dynamic related` thing (run time affect code)
whereas header is the place for all of the *static related* content

if like to write MyObject::helloWorld()
may have it here

myObject.h :

```
#include <iostream>


namespace nmspc{


class MyObject{
public:
   void helloWorld();
};

MyObject::helloWorld(){
          std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
       }
}
```

because `::` (scope resolution op.) is what name space or class/struct referred to
e.g. `nmspc::MyObject::helloWorld`

might be  `helloWorld` class inside `MyObject` class belong to `nmspc` name space
might be  `helloWorld` class belong to `MyObject` name space belong to `nmspc` name space.  etc

```
int main{

   MyObject obj1;

     //some code here

   nmspc::obj1.helloWorld();

   return 0;
}
```